# avoid ajax running twice with multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have this code that I want to run when someone changes an input or select field, obviously this is running twice because when I change the value of an input field then the select fields will change too. How can I make this code to not run twice but to work with both the selectors? I tried using an e.originalEvent statement for running only on human change but this will not work good cause I have some styled dropdowns that will change the values of the selected input through code so the code will not run..

```
//refresh form ajax.
jQuery('#BookingForm input, #BookingForm select').change(function(e){
    //jQuery('option:first-child', this).removeAttr('selected disabled'); //resetto il campo al change
    var dati = jQuery('#BookingForm').serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://justfunviaggievento.it/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: { action: 'booking_data_fetch', data: dati },
    success: function(data) {   
        //refresh dropdown sistemazioni
        if( !jQuery(e.target).hasClass('sistemazione')) {       
            var sistemazione = jQuery(data).find('#BookingForm select[name="sistemazione"]').html();
            jQuery('#BookingForm select[name="sistemazione"] option:not(:first-child)').remove();
            jQuery('#BookingForm select[name="sistemazione"]').append(sistemazione);    
            jQuery('select').niceSelect('update');
        }
        //refresh prezzo
        var prezzo = jQuery(data).find('#preventivo-prezzo p:first-child').html();
        jQuery('#preventivo-prezzo p:first-child').html( prezzo );
        jQuery('#preventivo-prezzo').removeClass("price-animation");
        setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('#preventivo-prezzo').addClass("price-animation") }, 100);
        //refresh supplementi
        var currentSupplemento = jQuery('#BookingForm .supplemento-monolocale').val();
        var maxSupplementi = jQuery(data).find('#BookingForm .supplemento-monolocale').html();
        jQuery('#BookingForm select.supplemento-monolocale').html( maxSupplementi ).val( currentSupplemento ).niceSelect('update');
        //refresh intestazione e immagine
        if( jQuery(e.target).hasClass('destinazione')) {
        var intestazione = jQuery(data).find('.box-preventivo h2 span').html();
        jQuery('.box-preventivo h2 span').html( intestazione );
        setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('.box-preventivo h2 span').addClass("price-animation") }, 100);
        setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('.box-preventivo h2 span').removeClass("price-animation") }, 1000);
        jQuery('.pagina-preventivo .box-preventivo:first-child').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 100, function() {
            // Animation complete.
            jQuery(this).css('background','url(/wp-content/uploads/media/justfun-viaggi-evento-preventivo-' + intestazione + '-3.jpg) no-repeat center').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 50);
        });
        }
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('errore JS');
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed this using bind and unbind inside and outside the function in this way:

```
//refresh form ajax.
function ajax(e){
    //UNBIND AFTER CHANGE
    jQuery('#BookingForm input, #BookingForm select').unbind('change');
    var dati = jQuery('#BookingForm').serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://justfunviaggievento.it/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: { action: 'booking_data_fetch', data: dati },
    success: function(data) {
        //refresh dropdown sistemazioni
        if( !jQuery(e.target).hasClass('sistemazione') && !jQuery(e.target).hasClass('numero-passeggeri') ) {       
            var sistemazione = jQuery(data).find('#BookingForm select[name="sistemazione"]').html();
            jQuery('#BookingForm select[name="sistemazione"] option').remove();
            jQuery('#BookingForm select[name="sistemazione"]').append(sistemazione);    
            jQuery('select').niceSelect('update');
        }
        //refresh supplementi
        var currentSupplemento = jQuery('#BookingForm .supplemento-monolocale').val();
        var maxSupplementi = jQuery(data).find('#BookingForm .supplemento-monolocale').html();
        jQuery('#BookingForm select.supplemento-monolocale').html( maxSupplementi ).val( currentSupplemento ).niceSelect('update');
        //refresh prezzo
        var prezzo = jQuery(data).find('#preventivo-prezzo p:first-child').html();
        jQuery('#preventivo-prezzo p:first-child').html( prezzo );
        jQuery('#preventivo-prezzo').removeClass("price-animation");
        setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('#preventivo-prezzo').addClass("price-animation") }, 100);
        //REBIND AFTER DOING STUFFS
        jQuery('#BookingForm input, #BookingForm select').bind('change', function(e){
            ajax(e);
        });
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log('errore JS');
    }
    });
}
//INITIAL BIND TO CHANGE
jQuery('#BookingForm input, #BookingForm select').bind('change', function(e){
    ajax(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
send2 = false;

//refresh form ajax.
jQuery('#BookingForm input').change(function(e){    
  sendQuery(e);
  send2 = true;
});

jQuery('#BookingForm select').change(function(e){
  if(!send2){ sendQuery(e);}  
  send2 = false;
});

function sendQuery(e){  
  //jQuery('option:first-child', this).removeAttr('selected disabled'); //resetto il campo al change
  var dati = jQuery('#BookingForm').serialize();
  jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "https://justfunviaggievento.it/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
  data: { action: 'booking_data_fetch', data: dati },
  success: function(data) {   
      //refresh dropdown sistemazioni
      if( !jQuery(e.target).hasClass('sistemazione')) {       
          var sistemazione = jQuery(data).find('#BookingForm select[name="sistemazione"]').html();
          jQuery('#BookingForm select[name="sistemazione"] option:not(:first-child)').remove();
          jQuery('#BookingForm select[name="sistemazione"]').append(sistemazione);    
          jQuery('select').niceSelect('update');
      }
      //refresh prezzo
      var prezzo = jQuery(data).find('#preventivo-prezzo p:first-child').html();
      jQuery('#preventivo-prezzo p:first-child').html( prezzo );
      jQuery('#preventivo-prezzo').removeClass("price-animation");
      setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('#preventivo-prezzo').addClass("price-animation") }, 100);
      //refresh supplementi
      var currentSupplemento = jQuery('#BookingForm .supplemento-monolocale').val();
      var maxSupplementi = jQuery(data).find('#BookingForm .supplemento-monolocale').html();
      jQuery('#BookingForm select.supplemento-monolocale').html( maxSupplementi ).val( currentSupplemento ).niceSelect('update');
      //refresh intestazione e immagine
      if( jQuery(e.target).hasClass('destinazione')) {
      var intestazione = jQuery(data).find('.box-preventivo h2 span').html();
      jQuery('.box-preventivo h2 span').html( intestazione );
      setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('.box-preventivo h2 span').addClass("price-animation") }, 100);
      setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('.box-preventivo h2 span').removeClass("price-animation") }, 1000);
      jQuery('.pagina-preventivo .box-preventivo:first-child').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 100, function() {
          // Animation complete.
          jQuery(this).css('background','url(/wp-content/uploads/media/justfun-viaggi-evento-preventivo-' + intestazione + '-3.jpg) no-repeat center').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 50);
      });
      }
  },
  error: function() {
      console.log('errore JS');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you have to do is maintain some state for when a request is in progress. Make sure to make this context specific - so if you only want to limit multiple requests for a specific use-case, name and manage this state accordingly. This means you will need multiple state variables (like `requestInProgress`) for different form fields and pages of your app; this is not meant to be a global request limiter

```
var requestInProgress = false;

function sendRequest() {
  if (requestInProgress) return; // no action
  
  // otherwise, run request logic
  requestInProgress = true;
  // ... your code

  jQuery.ajax({
    // make sure to set the boolean to false in both the 
    // success and error cases

    success: function(data) {
      requestInProgress = false;
      // ... your code
    },
    error: function(data) {
      requestInProgress = false;
      // ... your code
    },
  });
}
```